# How to Reorder tableview cell with a custom button, but not with move edit icon in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm developing an application with a new requirement of reordering tableview cell. In the tableview cell I should display only one label. When I select the entire cell it must get selected and able to drag the cell to the new position.

I have a `UITableView`, I am using the following code to manage reordering:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return YES;
}

-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    NSString *stringToMove = resourceDetailsArray[sourceIndexPath.row];
    [resourceDetailsArray removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [resourceDetailsArray insertObject:stringToMove atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
    [orderListTableView reloadData];
}
```

Can anyone please assist me a better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem in this code ?

Comment: I want to reorder the cell when i didselect the cell. or else here how can i hide the move icon?

Answer (score 1):

There's a library out there called [ObjcReorder](https://github.com/weirdyu/ObjcReorder) translate from [SwiftReorder](https://github.com/adamshin/SwiftReorder)。

Answer (score 0):

These lines of code had helped me alot. It works like a charm for my requirement i.e reorder the cell when long press the tableview cell.

```
- (IBAction)longPressGestureRecognized:(id)sender {

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender;
    UIGestureRecognizerState state = longPress.state;

    CGPoint location = [longPress locationInView:orderListTableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [orderListTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];

    static UIView       *snapshot = nil;        ///< A snapshot of the row user is moving.
    static NSIndexPath  *sourceIndexPath = nil; ///< Initial index path, where gesture begins.

    switch (state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {
            if (indexPath) {
                sourceIndexPath = indexPath;

                UITableViewCell *cell = [orderListTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

                // Take a snapshot of the selected row using helper method.
                snapshot = [self customSnapshoFromView:cell];

                // Add the snapshot as subview, centered at cell's center...
                __block CGPoint center = cell.center;
                snapshot.center = center;
                snapshot.alpha = 0.0;
                [orderListTableView addSubview:snapshot];
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

                    // Offset for gesture location.
                    center.y = location.y;
                    snapshot.center = center;
                    snapshot.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.05, 1.05);
                    snapshot.alpha = 0.98;
                    cell.alpha = 0.0;
                    cell.hidden = YES;

                }];
            }
            break;
        }

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {
            CGPoint center = snapshot.center;
            center.y = location.y;
            snapshot.center = center;

            // Is destination valid and is it different from source?
            if (indexPath && ![indexPath isEqual:sourceIndexPath]) {

                // ... update data source.
                [resourceDetailsArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];

                // ... move the rows.
                [orderListTableView moveRowAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:indexPath];

                // ... and update source so it is in sync with UI changes.
                sourceIndexPath = indexPath;
            }
            break;
        }

        default: {
            // Clean up.
            UITableViewCell *cell = [orderListTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];
            cell.alpha = 0.0;

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

                snapshot.center = cell.center;
                snapshot.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                snapshot.alpha = 0.0;
                cell.alpha = 1.0;

            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                cell.hidden = NO;
                sourceIndexPath = nil;
                [snapshot removeFromSuperview];
                snapshot = nil;

            }];

            break;
        }
    }
}


/** @brief Returns a customized snapshot of a given view. */
- (UIView *)customSnapshoFromView:(UIView *)inputView {

    // Make an image from the input view.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(inputView.bounds.size, NO, 0);
    [inputView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Create an image view.
    UIView *snapshot = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    snapshot.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    snapshot.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0;
    snapshot.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-5.0, 0.0);
    snapshot.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
    snapshot.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4;

    return snapshot;
}
```